# Transform Object to KeyValue pair Lodash

Tags: typescript, object, lodash

I have the below object
[{"id":"123","username":"user1"},{"id":"456","username":"user2"}]

I want to transform it to below using lodash
[{key: "123", value: "user1"}, {key: "456", value: "user2"]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: does it need to be lodash?

Comment: No, not sure of any easy way to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do any of the following:

```js
const data = [{ id: '123', username: 'user1' }, { id: '456', username: 'user2' }]

// 1st
const aa = data.map(x => {
  return {
    key: x.id,
    value: x.username
  }
})
console.log(aa)

// 2nd
const bb = data.map(x => ({
  key: x.id,
  value: x.username
}))
console.log(bb)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object is `obj`, then this would do the job, using [lodash/fp module](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
_.map(_.mapKeys(k => ({id: "key", username: "value"})[k]), obj)
```

where `_.map` is executing its first argument on every element of its second argument `obj`; given one of `obj`'s elements, `_.mapKeys(f)` applies `f` to its *keys*; `k => /* stuff */` looks up the object that connects `id`/`username` to `key`/`value` using `k` as the key.